# DataGrid not update object outside view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm encountering an issue of DataGrid and I tried whole day not found the solution.
Here I have a `DataViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Temp> Source { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Temp>();
public void AddTemp(Temp temp)
{
    Source.Add(temp);
}
```

which binded its dataContext to the view, contain a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="8" Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="All">
<!--some data grid column-->
</DataGrid>
```

and a `AddViewModel`:

```
public DataViewModel DataViewModel { get; set;}
public AddViewModel(Cami cami)
{
    DataViewModel = new DataViewModel();
}
public async Task Cap()
{
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
        //...
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); 
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await GetRealTimeDataAsync();
            timer.Start();
        }
        //...
    });
}
private async Task<Temp> GetRealTimeDataAsync()
{
    var (min, max) = await Cam.F.GetRealTimeTemp();
    var temp = new Temp
    {
        id = id,
        Time = DateTime.Now,
        Min = min,
        Max = max,
    };
    DataViewModel.AddTemp(temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Im using MVVM.CommunityToolkit. The problem is, when i debug, i see the `Source` in the `DataViewModel` actually updated. But the datagrid not update its row. Nothing happen.
But when i create `Temp` object inside the `DataViewModel` and update it via a button which binded `RelayCommand`, it works. But i need the data must be come from the `AddViewModel`, not the `DataViewModel` itself. I tried so many way, pass by constructor but it not help.
Any explain and help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the DataViewModel instance in the DataViewModel property of the AddViewModel is never assigned to the DataContext of the view. As a note, setting UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect on TwoWay of OneWayToSource Bindings. It is pointless here.

Comment: You should also not use a System.Timers.Timer. The Elapsed event handler is invoked on a background thread, not the UI thread. Without further action, a background thread is not allowed to manipulate an ObservableCollection that was created on the UI thread. Your Dispatcher.Invoke call is pointless here. Use a DispatcherTimer instead.

Comment: I removed the timer to see if it can update at least one row or not. Also removed the oneway/twoway. Still not work. I think its because they are just not same UI thread here. @Clemens

Comment: So how is the DataViewModel property supposed to be connected to the UI, i.e. where is it assigned to a DataContext?

Comment: `DataViewModel` is binded to a `DataView`, which is an User Control. But the `AddViewModel` is come from another view is `AddView`

Comment: That was not what I was asking. You call `DataViewModel.AddTemp(temp);` on a DataViewModel that is apparently not assigned to any DataContext. How is that supposed to update any UI?

Comment: I dont get it. What datacontext u talking about? I had `DataContext = new DataViewModel();` in the `.xaml.cs` and even `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:DataViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"`. Thats not enough?

Comment: just to ensure that View model maintain its instance, i also used dependency injection, add singleton this `DatViewModel` @Clemens

Comment: `new DataViewModel()` is a different object than the one in the `AddViewModel.DataViewModel` property. There is no singleton, at least not in the code in your question, and it is also unclear in which way DI would work here.

Comment: Remove it still not work. Im thinking of the way the thread treat the Model.

Comment: I moved binding context to mainWindow:
```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow(AddViewModel hvm, DataViewModel dvm)
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
        AddView.DataContext = hvm;
        DataView.DataContext = dvm;
    }
}
```
still not work. I start thinking its Visual Studio's bug :)

Comment: The bug is yours. You are still passing the wrong object to DataView.DataContext. Not sure what exactly you are intending, but you may write `DataView.DataContext = hvm.DataViewModel;`

Comment: wait, i written `MainWindow(AddViewModel hvm, DataViewModel dvm) ` , how i pass like you say, it will cause error compiling. If you wonder what i intend to do, im doing a  TabControl concept, and those view are tab Views. They are individual.

Comment: Beside, the context is binding to each view is perfectly fine. And i dont use a messenger here to communicate between view Model, but rather than testing if thread can be optimizing for saving more memory. And thats how they dont work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257108/discussion-between-zyp8x-and-clemens).